# Convert array with 5 items into array with 1 item

Tags: javascript

I have an array called 'xxx' with contains 5 items.

I would like to convert it in to a single array with the name newTableData[].

What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: `let t = []; t[0] = oldArray;` or `let t = []; t.push(oldArray);` ? I don't understand why you'd want to do that though

Comment: Why are we using pictures of code? Please post the array you *have* (or example 'input') and the array you *want* (example 'output'). Please read *both* the "*[mcve]*," and "*[ask]*," guidelines and then [edit] your question.

Comment: Did you mean that you want to flatten the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right, the problem is that you have an Array of Arrays of TableItems. Just use a `reduce` and `concat`:

```
xxx.reduce((acc, arrayWithTableItem) => acc.concat(arrayWithTableItem), []);
```

This way you take advantage of the fact that `concat` flattens a single level down, so from this:

```
[[TableItem], ...[TableItem]]
```

you end up with

```
[TableItem, ...TableItem]
```

It's easy peas from there

```
[xxx.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(x), [])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign array with 5 elements to the zeroth element of second array

```
var newArray = [];
newArray[0] = existingArray;
```

```js
var cars = ["Audi", "Volvo", "BMW", "Bentley", "Maruti"];
var newArray = [];

newArray[0] = cars;

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

For flattening your initial array, you can just do

```
const flattenedArray = [].concat.apply([], oldArray);
const newArray = [flattenedArray];
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is upvoted when it doesn't answer OP's question. Are people just upvoting because the code looks clean? You are just randomly assuming that OP wants to flatten his array when hes asking the opposite.

Comment: when i understand OP correctly, he wants to flatten his array of arrays. the provided code does exatly that.

Comment: But he wants to do the opposite, he has the array xxx in form of [1,2,3,4] and he wants [0 => [1,2,3,4]]

Comment: No, in the provided code, he has an Array of Arrays (of length 1). So, he has for example [[1], [2], [3], [4]]. But you are right, he wants [[1,2,3,4]] for some reason. so i will update my code accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. Thats absolutely not what he has. He has array `xxx` that has a length of `5` and is a flattened array. He wants to transform this array into an array `newTableData` that looks like `[ [1,2,3,4] ]` with the top level array having a length of `1`. Re-read the question.

Comment: can you just have a closer look at the screenshot OP posted? he clearly has an array of arrays there, where every nested array is exactly of length 1... [ 0: [TableItem], 1: [TableItem] ]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ES6+ you can use array destructuring `...`

```
cont newTableData[0] = [...xxx];
```